# Непредвиденное отсутствие конфликта при слиянии веток

Tags: git, git-merge

Сливаю 2 ветки - master (активная) и UrlHandlePoint:

```
$ git merge UrlHandlerPoint
```

При этом я предполагаю возникновение конфликта, поскольку код различается явно (в обоих случаях начинается на одной и той же (27-й) строке):

*master:*

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $about="Контент страницы \"О компании\"";
    $this->render('index', array('res'=>$about));
}
```

*UrlHandlerPoint:*

```
public function actionIndex($alias=false)
{
    $data=Data::getDataByAlias('o_kompanii',$alias);
    $this->render('index', array('res' => $data));
}
```

Но вместо того, чтобы отобразить конфликт и предложить его разрешить, git просто выбирает вариант ветки master.
Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался таки. Всё правильно, конфликт будет только тогда, когда изменены ОБЕ ветки. В моём случае состояние файла одной из веток было то же, что и в базовом файле. Т.о., git не находил конфликта, а просто применял изменения. Подробная схема здесь: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1Hmj89fLFA6ZG5JNjFBLWp1Z1U

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать наверняка, не зная всей предыстории обеих веток, но такое вполне возможно.  В git есть много замечательных методов автоматического слияния. Вполне может быть и такой, который просто переносит в целевую ветку коммиты из исходной, полностью уничтожая все следы существования последней. Из двух коротких веток он делает одну длинную. Естественно, такой метод слияния можно применить лишь тогда, когда ни один коммит в обеих ветках не конфликтует с другим, т.е. все они могут быть последовательно применены к той версии, которая является базовой для обеих веток.